# Pyspark: Pass parameter to String Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, parameters, sas

I'm quite new to PySpark and coming from SAS I still don't get how to handle parameters (or Macro Variables in SAS terminology).

I have a date parameter like "202105" and want to add it as a String Column to a Dataframe.
Something like this:

```
date = 202105
df = df.withColumn("DATE", lit('{date}'))
```

I think it's quite trivial but so far, I didn't find an exact answer to my problem, maybe it's just too trivial...

Hope you guys can help me out. Best regards

Comment: `df.withColumn('DATE', lit(f'{date}'))`?

Comment: `df = df.withColumn("DATE", lit(str(date)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolations i.e. **`{}.format() (or) f'{}'`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("DATE", lit("{0}".format(date)))
df.withColumn("DATE", lit("{}".format(date)))

#or

df.withColumn('DATE', lit(f'{date}'))
```

Comment: Thanks, the first two worked for me, the third one did not ... maybe it has to do something with the python version or functions? Anyway, solved!